# Accessing CPU registers while in reset using DSTREAM & DS5

Tags: jtag, ds5

The problem I currently have is that I wish to test SecureBoot on a device without permanently modifying a set of internal security registers with computed hash information. The way the documentation suggests you do this is to load a modified reset configuration blob such that execution gets "held off" at boot time. This gives you enough time to use JTAG to set the registers of interest before manually releasing the CPU.

However, my problem is that while the CPU is in reset I am not able to connect to and read register values. The JTAG device I am using is the [ARM DSTREAM](https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/debug-probes-and-adapters/dstream) along with their DS5 development environment. While in reset the toolset identifies the device to be "held in reset" but all attempts to use the "memory browser" feature returns no results.

This works fine, of course, if the CPU is first in a running state and I manually interrupt execution before attempting to read memory.

---

**tl;dr**

Can register values/memory content of a CPU be read over JTAG when the core is held in reset?

---

**EDIT**

Some of the specifics behind how to configure the device to hold-off at boot are very specific to this device, but the cores are held in a reset state when enabled. The SoC is a QorIQ LS1043A by NXP. This chip is a quad-core variant of the LS1021, which has an application note for this [here](http://cache.nxp.com/files/soft_dev_tools/doc/app_note/AN5227.pdf?fpsp=1&WT_TYPE=Application%20Notes&WT_VENDOR=FREESCALE&WT_FILE_FORMAT=pdf&WT_ASSET=Documentation&fileExt=.pdf). The reference to enabling the hold-off state are stated as setting BOOT_HO=1 in the reset configuration word.

All I see when trying to read from memory while the cores are held in reset is the following, regardless of the address being read: 
[image]

Comment: The answer will be specific to the SoC (not the core). It may be that you need to explicitly set the part to 'halt before reset' (the documented term is probably different, but the trick is that the debug logic needs to be out of reset, just the core not yet started). Please link to your references if they are public.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane, Ah. That makes sense. The documentation says simply to configure the device to hold-off at boot, which I have done. I am unsure about the debug hardware being out of reset though. For this to work as suggested it certainly *should* be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DS-5 supports accessing the processor registers whilst the non-debug logic of the core is held in reset **after a warm reset.** This is described in general terms [in the Debug Hardware Configuration Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0498j/ada1430321703618.html)

For this specific use case, it depends how the boot process is sequenced to achive this internally, and if warm boot is sufficient to provide the debug access in a generic way. With the `hold reset` bit set, the processor state is held after reset is de-asserted, until the bit is cleared.

Promoting a detail from the comments:

> As it turns out, I had to tell DS5 to use the namespace of the debug
>   hardware. This specific SoC had an AHB interface, so the command was
>   prefixed as such. e.g. **AHB_0:< addr >**

Comment: I *am* able to connect to the CPU without trouble. There is a reset button on the board that, if held, will cause the DSTREAM to fail on connect and DS5 will issue a report `Unable to connect .. hardware failed to initialize`. The device is not being held in reset, just the cores it seems. The debug hardware is at least capable of connecting to the debugger as the state of the debug instance changes to "connected". All four cores show "held in reset". Once here, though, none of the memory accesses work in DS5. Nominally only the 0th core will be "running" until after the bootloader executes.

Comment: The feedback I get from DS5 is `Unable to read from register CPSR. Target is in reset`.

Comment: And you can take core0 out of reset by clearing the `hold reset` bit? It may be correct that the CPSR is not accessible, that is a core register rather than debug (even though its accessed through the debug registers). Breakpoints and similar should be accessible, any of the 'external debug' registers are all I would expect to work.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot read *any* registers when in hold reset. There are event registers that explicitly state that during hold reset they should be programmable, but I just see a blank memory browser when attempting to read their contents. I updated my post with an image.

Comment: Sorry - I got Cortex-A7 from the part number when I looked, the control for Cortex-A53 seems to be entirely in the SoC power management registers. This implies a specific reset script will be required for DS-5 to enable the right parts (and that is consistent with the app-note).

Comment: I see. From the documentation can you discern what the steps to reset into this state should be? It is not immediately obvious to me. And sorry, the chip I am working with is an A53, but the document is for an A7 that is very similar

Comment: I don't have the NXP documents, and there is quite a difference, not just in the architected debug aspects, but also the suspend/retention features. All I can say is the registers which affect this will not be in the CPU block of the debug region. Probably there is a dedicated debug feature peripheral, I've seen these documented on mcu parts.

Comment: Are you saying that prior to reset there is register configuration that must take place in order to allow debug hardware to access memory? If not, what are you seeing in the app note? There really is no insight into what the "CCS" console session is doing -- but some configuration followed by a reset to allow register access seems reasonable.

Comment: If true, do you have any insight into which debug configuration registers might be useful for this task?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but there needs to be some control to de-assert dbg_reset (which is implicit in connecting the debugger) but keeping core_reset asserted. The app note implies to me that this is handled by the debugger init script. Its complicated by the fact that all cores can potentially be both clock and power gated under the control of the rest of the SoC. Typically there will be a memory mapped debug interface to this control, but nothing is architected in this area.

Comment: So, if I follow correctly, the steps would be to configure the debug hardware in some way to have access to the necessary registers followed by a soft reset to set each core's 
PC to zero?

Comment: This has been really helpful. As it turns out, I had to tell DS5 to use the namespace of the debug hardware. This specific SoC had an AHB interface, so the command was prefixed as such. e.g. `AHB_0:<addr>`.